# Why does std::rc::Rc need PhantomData?

Tags: rust

I know that `PhantomData` is intended to consume a lifetime or type parameter in a data type definition that would otherwise go unused. I was recently looking over the definition of `Rc` in the [Rust std lib](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/dee08ba55accecc13ed600e0fb6559fb28e7f480/src/liballoc/rc.rs#L278-L281) and noticed that it seems to employ `PhantomData`, but it looks like `T` is being used in the sibling field `ptr` as an [`NonNull<RcBox<T>>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/dee08ba55accecc13ed600e0fb6559fb28e7f480/src/liballoc/rc.rs#L259-L263). The docs say that `NonNull` is ["*mut T but non-zero and covariant."](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html) and go on to further extend that definition with the statement:

> Unlike `*mut T`, `NonNull<T>` is covariant over T. If this is incorrect for your use case, you should include some `PhantomData` in your type to provide invariance, such as `PhantomData<Cell<T>>` or `PhantomData<&'a mut T>`.

Hence, is it needed for variance or is it more because `NonNull` is effectively a raw pointer and `PhantomData` is needed to consume the elided lifetime as [this answer seems to imply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57846101/2748415)?

Comment: What elided lifetime? There are no lifetimes to elide.

Comment: Ah right, as there is no explicit lifetime, bounds on `T` for a lifetime, references of any sort, and raw pointers, we don't have any mention of lifetimes, but would that mean the `PhantomData` then is provided for the subtyping concerns? The sentence after what I quoted does go on to say "Usually this won't be necessary; covariance is correct for most safe abstractions, such as Box, Rc, Arc, Vec, and LinkedList." iiuc this means that supplying a phantom type makes the housing type invariant over `T`, but then `Rc` uses it and this sentence implies it's covariant over `T`?

Comment: `Rc` didn't always have a `PhantomData` field. Here is the commit where it was introduced: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/60dc10492ccdf785678d475172f2653aae9606da#diff-da456bd3af6d94a9693e625ff7303113R286

Comment: The commit message references [this conversation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27730#issuecomment-316432083), but that seems very old, and doesn't quite explain why it was done.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with drop logic, and not to do with lifetimes or subtyping at all. The message on the commit @PeterHall linked to, I think, supports my guess and suggests it has to do with the difference between `Shared` and `NonNull` (which replaced `Shared`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`PhantomData` is used here to tell the drop checker that dropping `Rc<T>` [may cause a value of type `T` to be dropped](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html#ownership-and-the-drop-check).

When we announce that we may drop a value of type `T`, the drop checker ensures that any lifetimes in `T` outlive the `struct` itself. It is this check that prevents the [following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67a4a5946f7d0372383116878ffa0ac0) from compiling. In this case, the generic argument to `Rc` is `PeekOnDrop<&'a u8>`, which has lifetime `'a`.

```rust
use std::{fmt, rc::Rc};

struct PeekOnDrop<T: fmt::Debug>(T);

impl<T: fmt::Debug> Drop for PeekOnDrop<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.0);
    }   
}

struct SelfReferential<'a> {
   value: Box<u8>,
   rc: Option<Rc<PeekOnDrop<&'a u8>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut sr = SelfReferential {
        rc: None,
        value: Box::new(1),
    };

    sr.rc = Some(Rc::new(PeekOnDrop(&*sr.value)));

    // `sr` would be dropped here, which could drop `value` before `rc`.
    // The destructor of `PeekOnDrop` would then try to inspect the (dangling)
    // reference, resulting in UB!
}
```

For a full explanation of the underlying logic here, see [the nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/dropck.html), but note that without `PeekOnDrop`, the previous example [compiles just fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d5d78e522a9e4ed14321cdc0c75469e2). This is because `Rc<T>` declares in its [`Drop` impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#889) that its generic parameter `T` is `#[may_dangle]`. In doing so, it promises that its `Drop` impl does nothing with the value of `T` that it owns except (maybe) drop it. Only when the drop checker recursively checks the `Drop` impl of `PeekOnDrop` and finds that it may access `T` does an error occur.

For completeness, [here's an example of an undefined program](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=528ce122067ee3ddfdf52acb1f5c6ff5) that lies by asserting that `PeekOnDrop`'s `Drop` impl does not access `T` using `#[may_dangle]`. The same undefined behavior would be exhibited in the original example if `Rc` did not use `PhantomData` to declare that it may drop a value of `T`.